# Magento shipping method

Tags: magento

I want to make a shipping method rule based on subcart total. If the subcart total > X then shipping method is free shipping but if subcart total < X then shipping method is flat rate.
I tried with the following rule, but it doesn't work.

If ANY  of these conditions are TRUE :
Subtotal  equals or greater than  75
Shipping Method  is  [freeshipping] Free
Subtotal  less than  75
Shipping Method  is  [flatrate] Fixed

The shipping method has to be automatically displayed on checkout and appropriate changes should be made to grand total.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's better to use the [table rates for this](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-do-i-set-up-table-rate-shipping).
You will need 2 lines in the csv

```
Country|Region|Postal code|Order subtotal (and above)|Shipping Cost
*      |*     |*          |0                         |10 - or the cost you want
*      |*     |*          |75                        |0
```

Comment: Table rates are great - if you can't find the `export` or `import` button in `system->configuration`, please keep in mind to select a store or storeview at the store switcher on the top of the left sidebar. Also don't edit the CSV file with Microsoft Excel, just use Notepad or other text editors, otherwise the import will fail.

Comment: Hi Stefan Brendle,  I have used many times Microsoft Excel for editing the csv files. But I dint get any issues with that ..

Comment: @Marius Table rates doesn't work, just like shopping cart rule. Shipping is charged even if the subcart total is greater than 75.

Comment: @are you sure that the table rates are enabled?

Comment: @Marius Ya I followed the magento tutorial. The checkout process show the table rate, but ends up charging for shippping irrespective of subcart total.

Answer (score 0):

@Marius your solution works, but there is a slight modification to it.

**Modification**: Rules in table rate should be defined  in **descending order** and not in ascending order.

This happened because of a bug in magento 1.7 or magento 1.7 handles the rules in different way compared to earlier versions.

Refer : http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/312623/ & http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/334406/

P.S: Excel can be used to edit tablerates.csv file.